# React Hook Form and React Select Not Working as Expected

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

Im trying to wrap React Select inside of a React Hook Form with the `Controller` wrapper component as per the docs (https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingControlledInputs)

```js
            <Controller
              name="ShiftCaptain"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <Select
                  {...field}
                  value={selectValue}
                  options={options}
                  placeholder={"Select Person"}
                  onChange={(e) => setSelectValue(e)}
                />
              )}
            />
```

On form submission, the value captured inside the React Select isnt being populated into React Hook Forms:
[image]

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: looks like you are using regular select, it should be ReactSelect?

Comment: @Sam according to the docs, it seems that ```Select``` is correct - https://react-select.com/home

Comment: @ayshlal check the https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-controller-5h1q5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `field` object of the `render` callback which you spread on your `<ReactSelect />` component has a `value` and a `onChange` property, which RHF needs to link the value and also changes to the value to it's internal form state. Right now you overwriting this, so RHF can't update the value. Try this and it should work:

```js
<Controller
  name="ShiftCaptain"
  control={control}
  defaultValue={null}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <Select
      {...field}
      options={options}
      placeholder={"Select Person"}
      
    />
  )}
/>
```

If you want to set a default value for your select after page load you should use the `<Controller />` `defaultValue` prop, which will pass the value to your `<ReactSelect />`.

Comment: I am using typescript and have this select component as a separate component. What would be the type for the `{...field}` props?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the this code sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-controller-forked-40t3s?file=/src/index.js

```
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedValue(e.value);
  };
<label>React Select</label>
          <Controller
            name="ReactSelect"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <ReactSelect
                isClearable
                {...field}
                value={selectedValue}
                onChange={handleOnChange}
                options={[
                  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
                  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
                  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
                ]}
              />
            )}
          />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesnt work however if i remove ```value={selectedValue}``` then im able to see the value on form submission. I use state to be able to set a default value on page load